# How to display the text in Radiobutton in the textView after Button is pressed in Android?

Tags: android

How to display the text in `Radiobutton` in the `TextView` when the `Button` is clicked?

This is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.rb1:
                if (checked)
                    tv1.setText('rb1 text');
                break;
            case R.id.rb2:
                if (checked)
                    tv1.setText('rb2 text');
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it a bit incorrectly. Firstly, you need to put your `RadioButton`s in a `RadioGroup` and get the reference of the radioGroup. Finally, attach a `OnCheckedChangeListener` to that instance. Something like this:

```
yourRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.rb1:
                if (checked)
                    tv1.setText('rb1 text');
                break;

                case R.id.rb2:
                if (checked)
                    tv1.setText('rb2 text');
                break;
    }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onCreate() method

final TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

```
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBt);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            yourTextView.setText(isChecked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked" );

        }
    });
```